# $2$ and $3-$fold covers for the figure $8$ graph

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have an assignment where I have to list all $2$ and $3-$fold covers for the figure $8$ graph and I am having some difficulties on how to think about it.

As far as the degree $2$ are concerned, first. Is there a way of intuitively picture the covering spaces for the graph? I know that the central vertex will have to be image of two vertices, and this helps. How do I guess all of the covers with this property now?

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thank you very much

Comment: 1st try to see that  how many edges and vertices  should be there in a 2 or 3 fold covering, and then try to figure it out that among them which could be your required covering space

Comment: ok so my figure eight has 1 vertex and 2 edges, right? So I would need to double it for a 2 fold cover, getting 2 vertices and 4 edges

Comment: do you know how many of each there are, up to isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

As you have written in your comment in the case of the 2-fold cover you will have two vertices with neighbourhoods mapping homeomorphically to the one downstairs so in the "lifted" you also 4 have small arcs mapping to the 4 arcs in the base vertex.

I would say to try and label the two loops in the figure 8 graph and fix an orientation. Then try to look at all the possible ways of connecting the "lifted" vertices by respecting the orientations.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How many 2-fold covers for the graph are there? I have three different, but my professor said there were four. And what about the 3-fold covers? I found there were seven, I don't seem to know how to prove that they are not isomorphic and why there are no more...

Comment: for the 2-fold cover did you count the disconnected one?

Comment: only the connected ones. that's maybe why he said there were 4

Comment: there are 3 connected ones and a disconected one

Comment: yes so I have them all. and what about the $3$-fold?

Comment: There are 7 3-fold covers, to show they are not isomorhic you might try to look at the action of $\pi_1$. In general these covers are classified by conjugacy classes of maps $\pi_1(X)\mapsto\Sigma_n$ which will tell you how many there are, you can read about this in Hatcher when he talks about the covering group actions

Comment: I am not able to use that tool yet! But thank you for your help.

Comment: What about computing deck groups for each of the covering? Trying to sketch it for each cover. I just think of the possible combination of edges?